# io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAUTHENTICATED: Credentials require channel with PRIVACY_AND_INTEGRIY

Tags: android, dialogflow-es

I am using Dialogflow Java Client library in my android app, to run the detect intent API as given in below link.

https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-java-client-v2/blob/master/samples/src/main/java/com/example/dialogflow/DetectIntentTexts.java

I modified the code given in above link slightly to authenticate the client first before sending the detect intent request. My sample code is as follows:

```
SessionsSettings sessionsSettings = SessionsSettings.newBuilder().setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).build();
SessionsClient sessionsClient = SessionsClient.create(sessionsSettings);
SessionName session = SessionName.of(PROJECT_ID, sessionId);
                    System.out.println("Session Path: " + session.toString());
TextInput.Builder textInput = TextInput.newBuilder().setText(text).setLanguageCode(langCode);
QueryInput queryInput=QueryInput.newBuilder().setText(textInput).build();
DetectIntentResponse response = sessionsClient.detectIntent(session, queryInput);
```

where

```
CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CredentialsProvider() {
            @Override
            public Credentials getCredentials() throws IOException {
                InputStream fileStream = appContext.getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("MyDialogflowProject-4cxxxxx.json");
                return ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(fileStream);
            }
        };
```

But I get the following error

> com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnauthenticatedException:
>   io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAUTHENTICATED: Credentials require
>   channel with PRIVACY_AND_INTEGRITY security level. Observed security
>   level: NONE
>           at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:73)

Can anyone please tell how to set the Security Level for SessionSettings in this case ?

Comment: Have you found any solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to update library versions you are using. On transport layer Security Level should be setup.

For example gradle dependencies from my hello world project which is working with dialogflow v2:

```
dependencies { 
    compile ("com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.12.0")
    compile ("io.grpc:grpc-netty:1.14.0")
    compile ("io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:1.14.0")
    compile ("io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.14.0")
    compile ("com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:0.10.0")
    compile ("com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage:1.38.0")
    compile ("io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:2.0.12.Final")
    compile ("com.google.cloud:google-cloud-dialogflow:0.55.1-alpha")
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have found out that I have set the IntelliJ environment variable to `FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8080` to use the Firebase emulators in the past.
Later I tried to push data to Cloud Firestore without removing that variable, but the attempts were unsuccessful with the error `PRIVACY_AND_INTEGRITY`.
After some time, I found the localhost setting and removed it. Once removed, I was able to push the data to the cloud without any issues.